# Face recognition: Ethnicity attribute

Tags: computer-vision, face-recognition, face-detection

I currently working on a project on discrimination (based on race) and have to evaluate a large number of pictures with respect to their age, ethnicity, gender etc. For this I would like to use a service like Face++ or Microsoft. However, none of these return the ethnicity of the picture. Face++ lists it in their documentation, but only returns "{"value": ""}", as documented on their site ([see here](https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/6329465)

Do you know of any facial recognition software the provides information on the ethnicity of a picture? Ideally it should be cheap/free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a half of ansser for yourquestion:
"Face++ can detect ethnicity as well. However, its ethnicity
classification is limited to white, black, or Asian; thus, it is
actually attempting to detect race, not ethnicity, as stated.
[Research](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICWSM/ICWSM18/paper/download/17839/17066&ved=2ahUKEwjy-rHo7t3wAhUo-yoKHRZGCVgQFjAKegQIChAC&usg=AOvVaw0wKMShDnPo9ZWa4QmzpTc9)"
That research may be usefull for you by itself, i guess.

Comment: Hefe is the second half. https://www.clarifai.com/models/demographics-face-recognition

Comment: And here is another interesting research https://sitn.hms.harvard.edu/flash/2020/racial-discrimination-in-face-recognition-technology/

Comment: thank you very much for the interesting links. I also found information on Face++ being capable of detecting a face's ethnicity and requested it using the API, however, the function does not appear to work, as it only returns this: "{"value": ""}"

In the codebook it's further stated that the app only returns this "value", when the ethnicity is requested: https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/6329465